# H2 Database - Create a trace file

Tags: h2

How does H2 Database create a trace file? I have used TRACE_MAX_FILE_SIZE 1, and i wanted to check whether trace file is splitting up properly. So, is there way to force h2 to create a trace file, to check upon the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H2 doesn't split trace file into many files. With `TRACE_MAX_FILE_SIZE something` you will have only up to 2 trace files, current `databaseName.trace.db` and previous `databaseName.trace.db.old`.

You can increase amount of trace output significantly with `SET TRACE_LEVEL_FILE 3`. You need to execute some commands in your application anyway, or you can connect to your database with H2 Console and click multiple times on Refresh button on toolbar of Console (not the refresh button of browser).

If you need more advanced logging capabilities, you need to use SLF4J instead. `slf4j-api` **and** some its **implementation** should be in the classpath of H2, you need to specify `SET TRACE_LEVEL_FILE 4` in H2 to redirect all trace output to SLF4J, and SLF4J should be configured for your needs with its own configuration.